# backbone.js fetch json success will not hit

Tags: json, backbone.js, fetch

i use fetch from backbone.js to load a json model but success will not hit.

```
var DialogModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : function() {
        return '/messages/getDialog';
    },
    parse : function(res) { 
        return res.dialog;
    }
});

var DialogView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),
    initialize: function() {
        var onDataHandler = function() {
            this.render();
        };
        this.model = new DialogModel();
        this.model.fetch({ success : onDataHandler});
      },
    render: function(){
        var data = {
                dialogModel : this.model
              };
        var form = new Backbone.Form({
             model: data
        });
        $(this.el).html(form.render().el);
    }
});
```

What happens now:
DialogView initialize is called.
this.model.fetch is called but the onDataHandler function will not be hit if success.
/messages/getDialog throws a json file back.
The json file is loading well as i can see in the network browser.

Thanks for your help!
Oleg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is due to a typical JS gotcha and not related to Backbone itself. Try

```
var that = this;
this.model.fetch({ 
    success : function () {
        that.render();
    }
});
```

The way you're currently passing `onDataHandler` is problematic as it will cause `this` to refer to the global object instead of the `DialogView`, when the function is called.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fS2G6/) demonstrates the problematic version vs one that works.

(You may also want to take a look at JS [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) which can shield you from this type of errors.)

Answer (score 0):

Even better is to listen for an event:

```
this.model.on("sync", this.render).fetch();
```

I ran across this question while looking for something else, but the currently accepted answer drives me nuts. There's no good reason to be sprinkling `this` and `that` all over your code. Backbone (underscore) includes a context parameter that you can bind to.

`that = this` makes no sense. If you **must** implement obsolete 2007-era Crockford patterns, then say `var self = this`. Saying `that = this` is like saying `left = right`. Everyone Stop.